# I can't find my friend on Skylanders

Tags: skylanders

My friend and I both play Skylanders. We wanted to become friends on Skyland but we can't find each other. I am playing on my desktop and he brought his laptop round. We are both in the same area but I can't see him and he can't see me. Is it possible we are on different servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to log in at the same time, be on the same island and on the same server, then click on "play now" at the same time. It worked for me, if it doesn't work for you just try again.